Why does update manager show unchecked updates which cannot be checked?
I just do not understand why update manager, when showing the list of updates the will get installed includes items where the checkbox in front is unchecked and where it is not possible to check the boxes / enable the updates?
What is a user supposed to do with that information?
Ubuntu Pro is enabled for that machine, so it is not the list of Pro updates ...

There is almost always more information visible if you run things from the command line.
Click 'Remind me later' in the dialog, then try what is below
More explanation:
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/about-apt-upgrade-and-phased-updates
Below you see the current state (at this writing) when doing so on 24.04.
Note the lines saying
The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
The following packages have been kept back:
... the items listed under phasing is to reduce traffic, not everyone gets it at the same time.
kept back things may well be installable but generally will replace or remove one package or more, if you install these you might also be hit by faults and bugs - yet to be detected.
( use sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade to get them installed )
$ sudo apt-get upgrade  
The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
  file-roller gnome-text-editor icu-devtools language-pack-en
  language-pack-gnome-en-base libicu-dev libicu74 libicu74:i386 liblzma-dev
  liblzma5 liblzma5:i386 python-apt-common python3-apt xz-utils
The following packages have been kept back:
  language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en
The following packages will be upgraded:
  language-pack-gnome-sv language-pack-gnome-sv-base libpython3-dev
  libpython3-stdlib python3 python3-dev python3-minimal
7 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,327 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,216 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://...


Phasing does not mean that the packages have a problem, just that they are not rolled out to everyone at once. https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/about-apt-upgrade-and-phased-updates

Right, 'phasing' and 'kept back' are obviously different thingies, but the text behind your link does not treat them as such - mixing them.

The fact that they reused a message that for decades meant "your package manager is hosed" to mean "this is totally ok" is one of the 3 reasons I am in the process of leaving Ubuntu.

Thank you for that explanation! The UI for this is terrible, mislieading/confusing though, why not grey out the checkbox and have a tooltip explaining that it is held beack (with a link to the explaining web page) instead? That would be UI 101, really.
